# Bootstrap right nav bar Mobile rendering issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issues that I'm trying to solve with the right side of my nav bar.

2) When viewing the nav on mobile. How do I get the "Login | Contact" right side nav bar to be displayed under the logo? I'd like it to be displayed on the 2nd line, left aligned under the logo.

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/waaBbWFaI1

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.artstation.com/assets/logo@2x-20dd909e895e83cd81b0f224ac66f10f.png" alt="Art">
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
              <li><a>|</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    line-height: 15px;
    float: left;
    }
```

try this css under media query width and height required LIKE:

```
    @media and screen (min-width:xyz and max-width: xyz) {
      .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    line-height: 15px;
    float: left;  
    }
   }
```

be sure to correct the media query syntax ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a media query to change the display to inline on both the `li` and `a`

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .nav>li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
        color: #777;
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

and then give it the Login | Contact links some `margin-top` too:

```
.nav navbar-nav navbar-right { margin-top:20px;}
```

Put it inside the media query as well

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav { clear: both; float: left; }
  .navbar-nav > li{display: inline-block; }
}
```